# Custom Status Not Changing (PyCord)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I cant figure out how to fix this

```
members = 0
o = "o"
for guild in client.guilds:
    members += guild.member_count
statusmessages = [
    "Made with ❤️ by epdev",
    "Watching over the epdev server",
    f"Helping {members} members!",
]
status = random.choice(statusmessages)

# Random status messages

async def randomstatus():
    while o == "o":
      await asyncio.sleep(10)
      status = random.choice(statusmessages)

# Events
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Main Bot Status: Running')
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.do_not_disturb, activity=discord.Game(name=status))
```

I expected it to change the status every 10seconds. It is just making it a random status once and not changing it

Comment: Could you give use some example of `random status`?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it's not changing is because randomstatus is never getting called. Also, there's a better way to call something every 10 seconds. You can use Pycord's [`tasks`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) library. For example, your code would be

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

members = 0
o = "o"
for guild in client.guilds:
    members += guild.member_count
statusmessages = [
    "Made with ❤️ by epdev",
    "Watching over the epdev server",
    f"Helping {members} members!",
]
# status = random.choice(statusmessages)

# Random status messages
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def randomstatus():
    status = random.choice(statusmessages)
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.do_not_disturb, activity=discord.Game(name=status))


# Events
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Main Bot Status: Running')
    # await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.do_not_disturb, activity=discord.Game(name=status))
    randomstatus.start()
```